# ewmstd min_periods parameter does not work as expected in Pandas 0.15.2

Tags: python, pandas

When I evaluate this in pandas 0.14.1:

```
res = ewmstd(DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), span=3, min_periods=2)
```

I obtain this as expected:

```
          0
0       NaN
1       NaN
2  0.892143
3  1.137248
4  1.323367
```

However with pandas 0.15.2, it becomes:

```
          0
0       NaN
1  0.707107
2  0.963624
3  1.177164
4  1.345243
```

As far as I can see, there have been changes to the ewm* functions' API, but not with the min_periods parameter. Is this a bug?

Comment: I don't really know the `stats` module in Pandas, but it looks like the previous behaviour was not intended (i.e., a bug), and they've corrected it. See [this commit](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/commit/0192f539bf0f7eb779403eaf3089b9f42627a02e). Or perhaps rather [this issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7884) & corresponding [pull request](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/7898).

Comment: Thank you for the links. However then it looks like the problem has crept back in..

Comment: I don't understand: how has it crept back in? What you're showing for 0.15.2 appears to be the intended behaviour (another [pull request](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/7926) states among others: "an entry will be NaN if the count of non-NaN input values through that point is < min_periods").

Comment: Thank you, I guess you're right! I have obviously read it the wrong way, as in: "skip at least min_periods before values are calculated".